# How to call a r script within rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Sorry for a question that might sounds silly. I have some r codes that I stored at`C:/Users/SQ/Documents`. And I am making a rmarkdown and would like to call two program from this diretory:`A.R` and `B.R`. How should I call those two codes?

I tried:

```
setwd("C:/Users/SQ/Documents/")
source(file.path("A.R")local = knitr::knit_global()) # not working;
read_chunk(file.path("B.R"))  ## still don't work
```

what should be the correct way to call those two program?
If I want my output to be store in `C:/Users/SQ/desktop`. should I set directory as `C:/Users/SQ/desktop` and use another way to call those two program? Could anyone give me some guidance?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to change the working directory. It should work as simply as:

Some text chunk....

````
#```{r, your_code_chunk, eval = TRUE, echo = FALSE}
#source("C:/Users/SQ/Documents/A.R")
#source("C:/Users/SQ/Documents/B.R")
#```
````

Obs: Ignore the `#` symbols, I had to use them to represent the backticks in here!

Next text chunk...

Comment: Dis I do anything wrong. I got following error code `
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : cannot open the connection`

Comment: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/source-script.html check this out.